# ggplot2 Adding data labels to grouped histograms chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, histogram

I have a table called "year" looking like this:

```
#   Year    Stars   n   pct

1   2015    1   778 26.5
2   2015    2   247 8.4
3   2015    3   286 9.7
4   2015    4   439 15
5   2015    5   1186    40.4
6   2016    1   678 22.7
7   2016    2   233 7.8
8   2016    3   256 8.6
9   2016    4   451 15.1
10  2016    5   1372    45.9
11  2017    1   501 24.3
12  2017    2   180 8.7
13  2017    3   215 10.4
14  2017    4   274 13.3
15  2017    5   894 43.3
16  2018    1   391 25.1
17  2018    2   125 8
18  2018    3   144 9.3
19  2018    4   196 12.6
20  2018    5   699 45
21  2019    1   474 22.4
22  2019    2   124 5.9
23  2019    3   168 8
24  2019    4   277 13.1
25  2019    5   1070    50.6
26  2020    1   148 25.3
27  2020    2   50  8.5
28  2020    3   64  10.9
29  2020    4   77  13.1
30  2020    5   247 42.2
```

Data represents have users have rated app from google play store through years. They rate it by giving 1 (bad) to 5 (great) stars.
I'm trying to make a chart which shows share of stars by star level and year using this code:

```
ggplot(year, aes(as.factor(Stars), pct)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(Year)), position = "dodge", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#05668D", "#028090", "#00A896", "#02C39A", "#4ecdc4", "#F0F3BD")) +
  ylab("Share of stars (in %)") +
  xlab("Stars") +
  geom_text(label=round(year$pct, digits = 1),
            position=position_dodge(0.9),
            size = 4, fontface = "bold") +
  ylim(0,50) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  ggtitle("Share of stars")
```

Unfortunately, I get two problems:
1) For some reason I get the following warning message:
Warning messages:

```
1: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_bar). 
2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
```

Meaning that data for 2020, 4 stars is missing though it should 13.1
2) My labels are all over the place while I would like them to be positioned above the corresponding column on the chart.

Could someone please help me with this problems?

Comment: 1) you have an observation of 50.6, but you also implemented a limit on the y-axis of 50. So that observation falls outside the range, is removed, and you get the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the grouping correctly for the dodging to work. Instead of using `ylim`, which cuts off one of your bars, we can turn off axis expansion which looks better for bars going down to 0. (You may need to use `ylim` with a higher value to make sure all labels are printed.)

```
ggplot(year, aes(as.factor(Stars), pct)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = as.factor(Year)), position = "dodge") + 
  geom_text(
    aes(label = round(pct, digits = 1), group = interaction(Stars, Year)),
    position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3, fontface = "bold", vjust = 0
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#05668D", "#028090", "#00A896", "#02C39A", "#4ecdc4", "#F0F3BD")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  labs(title = "Share of stars", x = "Share of stars (in %)", y = "Stars", fill = "Year")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem #1: You're getting that message because row #25 has a `pct` value of 50.6, and you're setting the maximum limit on the y-axis to 50.

Problem #2: Using `position_dodge2` in your `geom_text` will make the labels line up, and I think adding a little space above the bar makes it more readable so I also added `vjust = -1`

```r
ggplot(year, aes(as.factor(Stars), pct)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(Year)), position = "dodge", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#05668D", "#028090", "#00A896", "#02C39A", "#4ecdc4", "#F0F3BD")) +
  ylab("Share of stars (in %)") +
  xlab("Stars") +
  geom_text(label=round(year$pct, digits = 1),
            position=position_dodge2(width = .9),
            vjust = -1,
            fontface = "bold",
            size = 4) +
  ylim(0,50) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  ggtitle("Share of stars")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `position_dodge2` to fix the labels and get rid of the `ylim` to show all data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(year, aes(as.factor(Stars), pct)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(Year)), position = "dodge", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#05668D", "#028090", "#00A896", "#02C39A", "#4ecdc4", "#F0F3BD")) +
  ylab("Share of stars (in %)") +
  xlab("Stars") +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(pct, digits = 1)),
            position=position_dodge2(0.9),
            size = 4, fontface = "bold") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  ggtitle("Share of stars")
```

[image]